# Application error despite console displaying no errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I’ve been watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQzAHcojEKg) and I’ve run into an error. For some reason even though I fixed the unresolved external symbols errors, the application error is still available. https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3vrJ.jpg I don't know whether it's due to my computer because it says it's a 64 bit processing system, but nothing seems to work.

I tried using one [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WucagWc-LOM) in that I extract the sdl2.dll file then copy pasting it into  the windows32 file, and that still didn't work, and the properties panels don't have a compatibility tab on my computer. I'm not sure what to try next. Here's the code

```
 #include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(3000);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though your computer is 64 bit, you still can build and run 32 bit applications which link against 32 bit DLLs. (Platform `x86`) You can provide the target platform to your compiler. What compiler / IDE are you using? What error did you get? (Sorry, images are blocked on my side - company security paranoia.)

Comment: Error code 0xc000007b means INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, and generally occurs due to missing or corrupted system or application files. Please make sure that the dll you are trying to consume through your code is also built with the same configuration i.e.  if you are trying to build a solution with target as X64 architecture then the dll (sdl2.dll) should also  be to X64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The application does not start properly (0xc000007b)

The root cause is the lack of the required DLL, and the wrong version of the dll is also a possible reason, the report error of the two are exactly the same.

I noticed the following question. Is it possible that different versions caused your problem. But I tested and found nothing, it work. 
[image]

Have you performed this step? Copy SDL2.dll to the root directory of your project. This may also cause some problems, although the compilation is successful.

Of course, it is more likely that you are missing other system files or dlls. It is not easy to guess which file missing. If this is the case, I am sorry that I have no better suggestions.